# Session.save is updating the data in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Iam trying to sample code for saving student information in hibernate session.save().In that,student name,class,teacher id.

Table:Student

```
SNO SNAME             SCLASS         TNO
----------- ----------------------------------------
1 J D Alex            3                1
2 Goaty               2                2
3 J D Paul            7                1
```

Code:-

```
Transaction tx1=session1.beginTransaction();
Object o2=session1.get(Student.class,new Integer(3));
((Student)o2).setSclass("8");
session1.save(o2);
log.info("loadStdYearlyInfo:class "+((Student)o2).getSclass());
tx1.commit();
session1.close();
```

After saving the data and seen the output the class value is updated as 8 for  student id is 3

```
 SNO SNAME             SCLASS         TNO
    ----------- ----------------------------------------
    1 J D Alex            3                1
    2 Goaty               2                2
    3 J D Paul            8                1

[07/May/2012:10:03:06] info ( 3500): CORE3282: stdout: Hibernate: /* load com.aims.beans.Student */ select student0_.sno as sno0_, student0_.sname as sname1_0_, student0_.sclass as sclass1_0_, student0_.tno as tno1_0_ from student student0_ where student0_.sno=?
[07/May/2012:10:03:06] info ( 3500): CORE3282: stdout: loadStdYearlyInfo:class 8
[07/May/2012:10:03:06] info ( 3500): CORE3282: stdout: Hibernate: /* update com.aims.beans.Student */ update student set sname=?, sclass=?, tno=? where sno=?
[07/May/2012:10:03:06] info ( 3500): CORE3282: stdout: loadStdYearlyInfo2
```

How the updated the student class value in database?.save means inserting the data.But here value is updated.Please let me know.if any issues?.if any wrong the question sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of Hibernate.

When a record is loaded by a hibernate session , its instance will be in the [persistent](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-overview) state and managed by this session. If the values of the persistent instance are changed  , they are considered as dirty . During the flushing process ( ie. `Session.flush()`) , hibernate will find out all the dirty instances (We call this process `automatic dirty checking` ) and generate and issue the necessary SQLs for them to update the corresponding DB records to make sure that the DB records will have the same state as the corresponding instances held in JVM.

The flushing behaviour of a hibernate session is determined by the `FlushMode` . By default , it is the `FlushMode.AUTO`  which means that  `session.flush()`  will be invoked automatically before committing an transaction or execution of the query.  So in your code , though you do not call `session.flush()`   explicitly , the flushing process still occurs to issue these UPDATE statements.

Some remarks about the code:

```
Transaction tx1=session1.beginTransaction();   

/**
 * o2 is the in the persistent state and managed by session1
 */
Object o2=session1.get(Student.class,new Integer(3));

/**
 *As the value of o2 is changed , it becomes dirty and hibernate will issue an UPDATE SQL 
 *for it during flushing.
 */
 ((Student)o2).setSclass("8");

/**
 * save() only has effect on the transient instance. Nothing will 
 * be done when calling it on the persistent instance . So removing this line of code 
 * still produces the same result.
 */
session1.save(o2);
log.info("loadStdYearlyInfo:class "+((Student)o2).getSclass());

/**
 *I believe default FlushMode (FlushMode.AUTO) is used in here ,so session.flush()  will be invoked implicitly before tx1.commit().
 *Automatic dirty checking occurs and UPDATE SQL is generated and issued to the DB 
 *to update the dirty o2 instance
 */ 
tx1.commit();
session1.close();
```

Comment: Very thorough explaination. Taught me a few things. :)

Comment: what is Automatic dirty checking ?

Comment: Hibernate automatically tracks state change of the  persistent objects and update the dirty object during flushing. It is just a term to describe  this ability

Comment: I set session1.FetchMode(FetchMode.Manual) then it avoids updated the value.thanks

Comment: @KenChan-  Since save will do the update also via automatic dirty checkingso, we don't need saveOrUpdate right?? or there is any situation where saveOrUpdate is preferrable over save

Answer (score 1):

It's an expected behaviour.

Object returned by `get` is *persistent*. Call of `save` for persistent object is, basically speaking, ignored. But Hibernate automatically tracks changes in persistent object and updates the database accordingly, hence the `update` statement.

Comment: Since save will do the update also via automatic dirty checkingso, we don't need saveOrUpdate right?? or there is any situation where saveOrUpdate is preferrable over save

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are working with transactions. When you commit a transaction it automatically flushes any changes to an already loaded entity, in this case your Student object.
It does not save the object because it already has an unique identifier attached to the session.
I would have thought Hibernate would have thrown an exception because you tried to save an already attached object.

I hope this helps you out.